# Aligning InputLeftElement with Input in Chakra-ui

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to align `<LeftInputElement>` with the `baseline` or `center` of `<Input>`. The problem is that I'm using `fontSize="2xl"` and the elements end up misaligned.
Here's the code:

```
<HStack>
    <Text fontSize={"2xl"}>{recordName ? recordName : "Record"}:</Text>
    <InputGroup
      width="25%"
      padding={5}
      fontSize={"2xl"}
    >
      <InputLeftElement
        children={<Text fontSize={"2xl"}>{prefix}</Text>}
      />
      <Input
        variant="field"
        fontSize={"2xl"}
        borderRadius={20}
        placeholder="enter value"
      />
    </InputGroup>
    <Button fontSize={"2xl"}>
      <BsSearch />
      &nbsp; Find Record
    </Button>
  </HStack>
```

No matter what I do (display='flex', alignContent='center', alignItems='center', alignSelf='center') - not all at once and where applicable, of course, I end up with InputLeftElement having top aligned to the container and everything else is aligned correctly.
How do I keep InputLeftElement aligned and displaying inside Input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InputLeftElement` is absolute positioned to the top left of the `InputGroup` component, so it isn't going to take into account changes to the `InputGroup` component's padding. Adjust the `InputLeftElement` margin to account for the padding added to the `InputGroup`.

```
<HStack>
    <Text fontSize={"2xl"}>{recordName ? recordName : "Record"}:</Text>
    <InputGroup
      width="25%"
      padding={5}
      fontSize={"2xl"}
    >
      <InputLeftElement
        margin={5}
        children={<Text fontSize={"2xl"}>{prefix}</Text>}
      />
      <Input
        variant="field"
        fontSize={"2xl"}
        borderRadius={20}
        placeholder="enter value"
      />
    </InputGroup>
    <Button fontSize={"2xl"}>
      <BsSearch />
      &nbsp; Find Record
    </Button>
  </HStack>
```

[Chakra playground showing solution](https://play.chakra-ui.com/playground?code=N4Igxg9gJgpiBcICWBbADhATgFwATAB0A7XXACQGVsBDMAawBpjSAhAV22wiKZNwEkiaDr1KDh2ADIwAZtgCiAGxgoYRbKIFCOAcUwQ2aTQBUYADw3EAvrhn6UuAOQABMAAtqdTNQC0bJAD0mDC02I7ExOYYOLiQRADOeACCaGi4ALy4ABQAlBkAfPjMuMHYbJgkWcWkADz51aS4LLJYMA21lDT09XyNjTWmFrbc2BRIAF4w6cCOAExmio5W+QBKMJCYUPA1AYPYPX19NeK6+oa4AO5IUNhu6QQgswCsAKQPuGjUUFBIRADm0yeNhkIzGk2mcwWS1wACM-gBhCCKLAQ+LURQobhLA6HI4nKSyBTKVTqdq42EIpEoh4wxS0OhJRRoDwAOgALAAGDkPMm49xIRRQYJEaYDcx4EHqMFTGbzRbLAAKOz2+SsvMaARx5Nwx202HVfQAbtRMEhqOp7iAZEgYIKeb1tcMpRMZZD5QbGjCsLBMCsvkg2PFprMOWqHdq0HSwDA3EifZa1NgYJhcMbFGw2iAPZr1Tt8XoDGgtYcauxONwnaMXRC5diPcAAgAqHUseIUEKYdy4TW4RsBMOO7JIPIAMiIMPiaAA3LgAGK-KC4NYbKC5gJlrhEYu1AKdenb3BJOTJsk1PfdXN7SvSmtQ5bL73bXbig+1fNnNJXG53B7PN4gD4vh+f5AWBUFq1-BZ3jhRFkUwVF0UxIg63DEt8WkOQlBURMPVIGCqXgmkowZJlWU5bks1Q3EUBNP5flA3DYjcAUhTUUUr0lKtwVlO98iVZ8LFVbNX36fFGONU1zWwS1rVtVdKMHUhOJvHj3Sow4vU2ZM-R+QNg1DRjI1oGM42TBN1GTVN0Qze1BxzdS8z1AtDBE0sOE3a9q1UlDBwbZtSzbDsux7PsB0dLJh1wMcJ2nOcFyXdZvTXDduAPHZzzoYsdhxHJrGIEArCAA)

Comment: this is a perfect explanation but why wouldn't I just set `postition='relative'` instead of rigging margin value in?

Comment: As it goes using CSS, there are many ways to achieve the same result. Use the styles that achieve your requirement, make sense to you, and are pleasant for you to maintain.